# Get synonymes with awn

Tags: python, arabic

I use arabic wordnet to get synonyms, i want to integrate it to my code to get the matrix of similarity. The idea is if someone use the synonym of word it will give 1 what is mean similar. so there is the code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from numpy import zeros
from scipy.linalg import svd
from math import log
from numpy import asarray, sum
#from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
#from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
#from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer
#import nltk
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from snowballstemmer import stemmer 
from AWNDatabaseManagement import wn

titles = [
u" ذهبت الاخت الى المدرسة",u"تقع المدرسة في الجبال",
u"ذهب الام لزيارة ابنتها في المدرسة ",
u"تحضر الام الكعكة" ]


ar_stemmer = stemmer("arabic")

stopwords = [
u'ثم',
u'و',
u'حتى',
u'الى',
u'على',
u'في'
]

ignorechars = ''',:'!'''



class LSA(object):
def __init__(self, stopwords, ignorechars):
    self.stopwords = stopwords
    self.ignorechars = ignorechars
    self.wdict = {}
    self.dcount = 0    


def parse(self, doc):
    for word in doc.split(" "):
        stem = ar_stemmer.stemWord(word.strip())
        #synsets = wn.get_synsetids_from_word(stem)
        #for s in synsets:
              #wn._items[s].describe()
        if not stem or stem in self.stopwords:
            continue
        elif stem in self.wdict:
            self.wdict[stem].append(self.dcount)
        else:
            self.wdict[stem] = [self.dcount]
    self.dcount += 1


def build(self):
    self.keys = [k for k in self.wdict.keys() if len(self.wdict[k]) > 1]
    self.keys.sort()
    self.A = zeros([len(self.keys), self.dcount])
    for i, k in enumerate(self.keys):
        for d in self.wdict[k]:
            self.A[i,d] += 1
```

And what I want to put is, in the place of رَاحَ I will put stem in the class parse.

```
from AWNDatabaseManagement import wn
synsets = wn.get_synsetids_from_word(u"رَاحَ")
print synsets
for s in synsets:
wn._items[s].describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem, you text is not vocalized and also the stemmer normalize the words before stemming them while the Arabic Wordnet require words to be vocalized exactly as it is stored.

You should patch the wordnet to list words by unvocalized version of words.